# Temperature table using for loop c++

Tags: c++, c++11

Super new to coding and I've been stuck for awhile on this question. I need to make a program that inputs the temperature in Celsius and an increment that is inputted for a total of 20 lines. In the process it converts to Fahrenheit, Kelvin, and Rankine. That is all fine but I can't get the values to increment by my input.

e.g., As it should look:

Enter temperature in Cel: 50

Enter increment: 5

```
  Cel   Far   Kel  Rank
```

1 - 50   ...............................

2 - 55   ..............................

3 - 60   ..............................

.
.
.
.

20 - 150 .............................

I can't get the values to increment at all. Being reading my notes and looking online to understand the issue but no luck.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int CELS; // celsius entry
    int x; // x = input value for increment
    double FAH = (CELS * (9.0 / 5) + 32); // farenheit conversion
    double KEL = (CELS + 273.15); // kelvin conversion
    double RANK = ((CELS + 273.15) * (9.0 / 5)); // rankine conversion

    cout << "Enter the temperature in celsius: ";
    cin >> CELS;
    while ((CELS < -273.15) || (CELS > 5000))
    {
        cout << "ERROR: out of range." << endl;
        cout << "Enter the temperature in celsius: ";
        cin >> CELS;
    }
    cout << "Enter the increment value: ";
    cin >> x;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "         #      Cels       Fahr     Kel       Rank" << endl;

    cout << right;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
    { //
        for (double j = CELS; j <= CELS; x++)
        { //
            for (double k = (CELS * (9.0 / 5) + 32);
                    k <= (CELS * (9.0 / 5) + 32); x++)
            {
                for (double m = (CELS + 273.15); m <= (CELS + 273.15); x++)
                {
                    for (double n = ((CELS + 273.15) * (9.0 / 5));
                            n <= ((CELS + 273.15) * (9.0 / 5)); x++)
                    {

                        cout << setw(10) << i << setw(10) << j << setw(10) << k
                                << setw(10) << m << setw(10) << n << endl;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And ignore why I have my formulas in the for loop. Formulas were not working using the declared variables so have just done this in the mean time.

Comment: "Formulas were not working using the declared variables"... `CELS` is undefined and you're trying to use it in an assignment.

Comment: Suggestion: Give your variables meaningful names, especially when posting your code for help.

Comment: C++ programs run top-down.  Those lines at the beginning of main() using `CELS` are executed -- they are not stored away in a function or formula somewhere to be used later.  Thus you're computing `KEL`, `FAH`, and `RANK` with a garbage `CELS` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some user defined functions to calculate the conversion from Celsius to the other units.

Then you only need one loop:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::setw;

// define some constant
const double zero_point = 273.15;
constexpr double factor = 9.0 / 5.0;
const double max_cels = 5000;

// farenheit conversion
double cels_to_far( double cels ) {
    return cels * factor + 32.0;
}

// kelvin conversion
double cels_to_kel( double cels ) {
    return cels + zero_point;
}

// rankine conversion
double cels_to_ran( double cels ) {
    return ( cels + zero_point ) * factor;
}

int main()
{
    double temp_cels;
    double delta_t;

    cout << "Enter the temperature in celsius: ";
    cin >> temp_cels;
    while ((temp_cels < -zero_point) || (temp_cels > 5000)) {
        cout << "ERROR: out of range.\n";
        cout << "Enter the temperature in celsius: ";
        cin >> temp_cels;
    }
    cout << "Enter the increment value: ";
    cin >> delta_t;
    cout << "\n         #      Cels      Fahr       Kel      Rank\n";

    // output loop
    for ( int i = 0; i < 20; ) { 
        cout << setw(10) << ++i << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2)
            << setw(10) << temp_cels 
            << setw(10) << cels_to_far(temp_cels) 
            << setw(10) << cels_to_kel(temp_cels)
            << setw(10) << cels_to_ran(temp_cels) << std::endl;
        temp_cels += delta_t;
    }
}
```

The output is as expected ( 50° Celsius and increment of 5°):

```
 #      Cels      Fahr       Kel      Rank
 1     50.00    122.00    323.15    581.67
 2     55.00    131.00    328.15    590.67
 3     60.00    140.00    333.15    599.67
 4     65.00    149.00    338.15    608.67
 5     70.00    158.00    343.15    617.67
 6     75.00    167.00    348.15    626.67
 7     80.00    176.00    353.15    635.67
 8     85.00    185.00    358.15    644.67
 9     90.00    194.00    363.15    653.67
10     95.00    203.00    368.15    662.67
11    100.00    212.00    373.15    671.67
12    105.00    221.00    378.15    680.67
13    110.00    230.00    383.15    689.67
14    115.00    239.00    388.15    698.67
15    120.00    248.00    393.15    707.67
16    125.00    257.00    398.15    716.67
17    130.00    266.00    403.15    725.67
18    135.00    275.00    408.15    734.67
19    140.00    284.00    413.15    743.67
20    145.00    293.00    418.15    752.67
```

Answer (score 0):

You need exactly one for loop, incrementing by x. ( The nested for loops are a mistake )

Start with the one, single for loop that you need: the one that counts through the lines of the output table.

In the body of the loop, calculate everything you need for that line, and output it.

Something like this:

```
for( int line_count = 0;
     line_count < 20;
     line_count++ )
{
    double line_temp_celsius =
          start_celsius + line_count * celsius_increment;
    // calculate the other values based line_temp_celsius
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The calculation must be in the loop where you change the value of `CELS`.
There should be a single loop. The result looks like this. See [live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c8796d10f4492f95)

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++, CELS+=x)
{ 
    double FAR = (CELS * (9.0 / 5) + 32); // farenheit conversion
    double KEL = (CELS + 273.15); // kelvin conversion
    double RANK = ((CELS + 273.15) * (9.0 / 5)); // rankine conversion

    cout << setw(10) << i   << setw(10) << CELS << setw(10) << FAR 
         << setw(10) << KEL << setw(10) << RANK << endl;
}
```

Comment: This works except its repeating it 20 times for each set of #1-20

Comment: Forget that, fixed it, works perfectly. Thanks thomas, super helpful

Comment: And better would be to create dedicated functions to convert from one unit (Celsius) to another. (And so, comment might be removed).

Comment: @Jarod42 And even better to refactor the entire code so that not a single line remains the same.